# Access csv file in tmp folder from AWS Lambda C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, streamreader

I try to access CSV file in C#, which packaged with Lambda deployment. It is not in S3. I use this code :

```
var basePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(basePath, "100_record.csv") )) 
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
var records = csv.GetRecords<BizItem>().ToList();
if (records.Count < 10)
{
   Console.WriteLine("processing less than 10 items");
}
```

I get this error

> Could not find file '/var/task/100_record.csv'.: FileNotFoundException
> at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo,

what could possible be wrong ?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary , how to upload the file to /tmp folder ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you looking to write a file to it? Or are you trying to read a file that was uploaded with your ZIP package?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary , exactly, I want to read a file that was uploaded with my ZIP package.

Comment: Try `string basePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT");` - does that change anything?

Comment: the issue that I need a path to my file. Where is the file is uploaded if I included it in the package ? it is not in tmp folder.

Comment: It will be at `{LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/100_record.csv` so if you change your base path to the above, it should work (assuming you have not put it in any nested folders). If that also does not work, please share the full exception trace.